# Problem/error 'Property ''xs' does not exist on type 'TensorContainer' in angular project with tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to get the tensorflow.js example from the tensorflow.js-website running within my existing angular project. I basically copied the code from the website and integrated it into my component, but I'm receiving an error message.

Since I'm pretty new to angular I don't have any idea on how to fix the error.

```
export class MotionAnalysisComponent implements OnInit{
async run() { 
// We want to predict the column "medv", which represents a median value of 
// a home (in $1000s), so we mark it as a label.
const csvUrl = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-examples/multivariate-linear-regression/data/boston-housing-train.csv';
const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(
csvUrl, {
  columnConfigs: {
    medv: {
      isLabel: true
    }
  }
});

// Number of features is the number of column names minus one for the label column.

const numOfFeatures = (await csvDataset.columnNames()).length - 1;

// Prepare the Dataset for training.
const flattenedDataset =
  csvDataset
   .map(({xs, ys}) =>
    {
    // Convert xs(features) and ys(labels) from object form (keyed by
    // column name) to array form.
    return {xs:Object.keys(xs), ys:Object.keys(ys)};
  })
.batch(10);

// Define the model.
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  inputShape: [numOfFeatures],
  units: 1
}));
model.compile({
  optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.000001),
  loss: 'meanSquaredError'
});

// Fit the model using the prepared Dataset
return model.fitDataset(flattenedDataset, {
  epochs: 10,
  callbacks: {
    onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
      console.log(epoch + ':' + logs.loss);
    }
  }
});
}
}
```

I'm receiving the following two error messages:

- `Property 'xs' does not exist on type 'TensorContainer'`
- `Property 'ys' does not exist on type 'TensorContainer'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typings error can be avoided by settings the map argument to `any`

Then you would need to cast `xs` and `ys` to allow type completion. Here `xs` and `ys` are simply object of key value elements.

```js
.map((val: any) => {
    const {xs, ys} = val // can cast xs and ys to appropriate type
    // for instance it can be const {xs, ys} = val as {xs: Object, ys: Object}
     return {xs:Object.keys(xs), ys:Object.keys(ys)};
})
```

Or it can also be avoided by casting the type - parameter of `map`

```
.map((val: {xs: Object, ys: Object}) => {
     return {xs:Object.keys(xs), ys:Object.keys(ys)};
})
```

To be thorough `xs` and `ys` should respectively have the type of the feature and label of the dataset.

Given the data of boston-housing.csv, the type Features can be as follow

```
interface Features {
  crim: number;
  zn: number;
  inus: number
  ...
}
```

And the type Labels

```
interface Features {
  medv: number
}
```

Casting With these types, the previous code will have auto-completion for the property on xs and ys if necessary

```
.map((val: any) => {
        const {xs, ys} = val as {xs: Features, ys: Labels}
         return {xs:Object.keys(xs), ys:Object.keys(ys)};
 })
 // or 
.map(((val: {xs: Features, ys: Labels }) => {
        const {xs, ys} = val as {xs: Features, ys: Labels}
         return {xs:Object.keys(xs), ys:Object.keys(ys)};
 })
```

Granted, it is not really useful in these scenario to type exactly the Features or labels, since one is only interested in returning the values of the dataset. If this method is to be used as a generic way of converting csv dataset to tensor batches, leaving `xs` and `ys` with type `Object` should rather be the way to go.

To go a step further, if the dataset created is to have a type that matches exactly the field of the csv, one might create a `dataType` for the dataset

```
interface DataType {
    xs: Features;
    ys: Labels;
}    

const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(/* ... */) as unknown as Dataset<DataType>;
```

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

The problem is that the [Datasets](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#class:data.Dataset) in Tensorflow.js are by default of type `tf.data.Dataset<TensorContainer>`, which means that TypeScript assumes an object of [`TensorContainer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/81225adc2fcf6fcf633b4119e4b89a3bf55be824/tfjs-core/src/tensor_types.ts#L41) for your DataSet.

### Solution

To help TypeScript, you can give your DataSet a specific type when creating it. As you are reading an object with multiple attributes inside, you can extend the interface [`TensorContainerObject`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/81225adc2fcf6fcf633b4119e4b89a3bf55be824/tfjs-core/src/tensor_types.ts#L44).

**Code Sample**

```js
import { TensorContainerObject } from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { Dataset } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-data';

interface DataType extends TensorContainerObject {
    xs: tf.Tensor;
    ys: tf.Tensor;
}

const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(/* ... */) as any as Dataset<DataType>;
csvDataset.map(({xs, ys}) => {
    // ...
});
```

Unfortunately, as Tensorflow.js is very opinionated about its Dataset types (because an union is used for the default [`TensorContainer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/81225adc2fcf6fcf633b4119e4b89a3bf55be824/tfjs-core/src/tensor_types.ts#L41)), you have to use an `any` cast before you can cast it to the actual `Dataset<DataType>` interface.

But after that cast, all functions working on the `DataSet` like `map` automatically know the correct type. Instead of using `tf.Tensor` above, you could even use a type like `tf.Tensor1D` to be even more specific.

### Alternative solution: *Just make the error go away*

As already addressed in the other answer: If you do not care about types and TypeScript and you just want to make the error disappear, you can cast any problematic variables into [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any).

**Code Sample**

```js
csvDataset.map(({xs, ys}: any) => {
    // ...
});
```

Keep in mind, that this disables any type checking for the variable.