# Tensorflow JS learning data too big to fit in memory at once, how to learn?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I have the problem that my **dataset became too large to fit in memory at once** in tensorflow js. What are good solutions to learn from all data entries? My data comes from a mongodb instance and needs to be loaded asynchronously.

I tried to play with generator functions, but couldnt get async generators to work yet. I was also thinking that maybe fitting the model in batches to the data would be possible?

It would be great if someone could provide me with a minimal example on how to fit on data that is loaded asynchronously through either batches or a database cursor.

For example when trying to return promises from the generator, I get a typescript error.

```
    const generate = function* () {
        yield new Promise(() => {});
    };

    tf.data.generator(generate);
```

`Argument of type '() => Generator<Promise<unknown>, void, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Iterator<TensorContainer, any, undefined> | Promise<Iterator<TensorContainer, any, undefined>>'.`

---

Also using async generators doesnt work:

Async generators result in a type error

```
tf.data.generator(async function* () {})
```

throws
`Argument of type '() => AsyncGenerator<any, void, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Iterator<TensorContainer, any, undefined> | Promise<Iterator<TensorContainer, any, undefined>>'.`

Comment: Don't yield promises - make the generator async, do work as you like and yield the results?

Comment: async generators result in a type error `tf.data.generator(async function* () {})` throws `Argument of type '() => AsyncGenerator<any, void, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Iterator<TensorContainer, any, undefined> | Promise<Iterator<TensorContainer, any, undefined>>'.` @AKX

Comment: Isn't your question literally answered in the tensorflow documentation? You can use `fitDataset()` to work with streaming data or data that doesn't fit in memory. There is an example of a generator: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/train_models

Comment: @Kokodoko yes but I need to get it working with ASYNC generators since I need to load my data asynchronously

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with tensorflow per se, but this sounds more like a general large data handling problem. You have a couple of different issues at hand here as far as I can tell.

### Asynchronity / Promises

There are a couple of spots where `async / await / promises` could come into play here. One being when you read data from mongodb - this is an asynchronous operation which you need to wait to finish before you can use that data with tensorflow.

<s>Another possible spot where you might need asynchronity is when you are training your tensorflow model.</s> After looking at the [tensorflow.js documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/4.8.0/) it seems like there aren't any asynchronous functions when it comes to training the models, so it seems like all training is done synchronously. However, there are asynchronous functions [for interference](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/4.8.0/#tf.GraphModel.predictAsync) for example.

There are basically two options for reading large amount of data from a database:

**Streaming**

Streaming data allows us to effectively read as much data as we want, without ever running out of memory. Data streaming is like having a configuration of different pipes, opening the faucet and having the data just flow through the whole thing as fast as the pipes allow - the "water" won't pool anywhere which would lead into out of memory errors, but instead the flow just slows down if something is "clogging" the pipeline.

Here's one article which shows how to implement data streaming with node.js and mongodb: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/transform-export-bulk-database-response-without-memory-overflow-using-mongodb-node-js-streams-bcbb3415dd9c

Mongodb stream-API documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/v3.6/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/#stream-api

**Batch-reading**

Another option is to read the data in batches. This implementation includes some kind of loop, asynchronously reading in a batch of data, feeding the batch to tensorflow and repeat. MondobMight look like this:

```
async function batchReadAndTrainTensforFlow() {
    const cursor = collection.find({});

    while (await cursor.hasNext()) {
        const data = await cursor.next();

        // feed the data to tensorflow here
    }
}
```

Note that mongodb doesn't exactly support batch reads, at least not in the conventional sense. The above example arguably reads in batches, it's just that the batch size is one. For tensorflow model training purposes though, you could [accumulate data locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72137813/how-to-query-data-from-mongodb-batch-by-batch-using-nodejs-and-mongoose) until some batch size N and then pass that to tensorflow.

### Training the model

This is where I don't have any specific information about tensorflow.js, but what needs to be done here is to find the correct tensorflow.js api method for training the model in batches / parts. When we know the correct method to use, which will most likely be a synchronous method, then it's just a matter of making a some kind of loop where we read and feed the training data in parts to tensorflow.js.

### Note about generators

Generators are not needed here. I would actually go as far as to say that you will probably never come across an issue for which the proper solution was to use generators. I know I haven't, and I have ~15 years of experience working with JavaScript.

Generator functions are functions which can halt their execution and then continue where they left off. They are mostly used to create iterators, so when you run into something like `cursor.next()` as seen in my short code snippet above, the chances are that there is a generator function behind it. So unless you are writing a JavaScript-library yourself, you probably won't ever need them and you won't need them here, as the mongodb library already implements one for you - here it's just a matter of correctly using it to yield and feed data for the training of your model.

### Lastly

Essentially what you need is simply some kind of loop for reading data from mongodb and then feeding it to tensorflow. It doesn't really matter whether you do it asynchronously or synchronously, as the difference is effectively just either having `awaits` in your code or not.

If you wanted to somehow parallellize the reading and training, then you would **have to** do it asynchronously, but that is a whole different beast and you'd most likely need workers and/or child-processes for that, assuming that tensorflow.js even allows some kind of parallellized model training.

The main problem to solve here is to find out how to train tensorflow model in parts and then just having a loop which reads the data and does the training in parts. That's all there is to it as far as I can see.

### Edit

Going by the [tensorflow.js documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.generator), I suppose something like this could work:

```
async function* makeAsyncIterator() {
    const cursor = collection.find({});

    const iterator = {
        next: async () => {
            while (await cursor.hasNext()) {
                const data = await cursor.next();

                // Perform transformations on data if needed

                yield data;
            }
        }
    }

    return iterator;
}

const ds = tf.data.generator(makeAsyncIterator);
await ds.forEachAsync(e => console.log(e));
```

Since the `tf.data.generator` expect an iterator with a `next()`-function which returns with [a format](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.generator:%7E:text=The%20returned%20iterator%20should%20have%20.next()%20function%20that%20returns%20element%20in%20format%20of%20%7Bvalue%3A%20TensorContainer%2C%20done%3Aboolean%7D.) `{ value: TensorContainer, done: boolean }`, this should work out because `yield` itself returns with a similar format per the [yield documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield#using_yield). When the `.hasNext()` finally breaks the loop, the iterator should also correctly yield `{ value: undefined, done: false }`.

As for what exactly is the `TensorContainer` type, [here is one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57793680/2284136) I found which explains one way to manage the types and also links to the [tensorflow.js repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/81225adc2fcf6fcf633b4119e4b89a3bf55be824/tfjs-core/src/tensor_types.ts#L41) where the `TensorContainer` type is defined. Simply put, the `value` in the returned object can be any of `void|Tensor|string|number|boolean|TensorContainerObject|TensorContainerArray|Float32Array|Int32Array|Uint8Array`, so you might have to do some transformation on your data before returning (commented on the sample code).

Contrary to what I stated before, it does seem that the simplest way here is to make an iterator of your own to better control what is returned by the `next()`-function to support tensorflow.js's needs. Feels a bit off to me, but I suppose if it works, then it must not be all that bad.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer @Swiffy, but this doesnt really add a lot to the solution. I'm aware of the approaches of batching and streaming. The question is on how to specifically apply streaming with a tensorflow generator function for a dataset that streams data asynchronously. I'd like tensorflow to take care of the dataset generation once I provide a cursor to the db and a way to create tensors from it.

I couldnt find something about it in the internet yet. Probably I'll just advance with batching the data.

Comment: @Sirhennihau I've edited my answer with some kind of sample code. Can't really do much more than that since there isn't enough context regarding what your data looks like, what the surrounding code looks like and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried again for two hours to get it working with an iterator object as you suggested. But I didnt succeed yet to get to the point where I can log from the generator object. The generation just doesnt work yet. Your snippet has multiple errors, f.e. you can only yield in generators and also still throws a type error `Argument of type '() => AsyncGenerator<never, { next: () => Promise<void>; }, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Iterator<TensorContainer, any, undefined> | Promise<Iterator<TensorContainer, any, undefined>>'.`

Comment: I think at that point of time I will just continue with a manual batching approach, even though I would have liked that one to work.